# How can I complete match between arrays in arrays by using enumerate?

Tags: python, enumerated-types

I have 2 array,

```py
x_test=[(2 1 3 2 5 1),(2 1 3 4 1 2).........] # len(x_test)=172
y_test=[2,1,3,4,5,1,3,5.....................] # len(y_test)=172
```

How can I match them by index like `(2 1 3 2 5 1) 2` ;`(2 1 3 4 1 2) 1`.

```py
print(list(enumerate(x_test,y_test)))
```

error:

```
'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

```py
print(list(enumerate(x_test,y_test)))
print(list(enumerate(x_test,y_test)))
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-491946acd941> in <module>
----> 1 print(list(enumerate(x_test,y_test)))

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `zip`:

```
x_test=[(2,1,3,2,5,1),(2,1,3,4,1,2)]
y_test=[1,2]

for a, b in zip(x_test, y_test):
    print (a,b)

#(2, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1) 1
#(2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2) 2
```